# Myetherwallet says not a valid address on Poloniex

Tags: poloniex

So, I've tried this multiple times.  I put myetherwallet address in at Poloniex to withdraw some of my coins and put them back into myetherwallet and everytime i put my address in, it says "invalid address".  Anybody experience this?  Not sure if the address has to be converted?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

An Ethereum address is 40 hex characters. Some interfaces expect the address to be prepended with a "0x" and some interfaces will not accept this. myetherwallet prepends the "0x". Try to paste the address without the "0x".